# How to update two different tables using a single UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to update two tables with a single statement  like this

```
db2 update catentry, catentdesc 
set catentry.buyable=0,
    catentdesc.published=0 
where catentry.catentry_id=catentdesc.catentry_id 
  and catentry.partnumber='some value'
```

but getting an error

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any database that supports this. Why do you wish to do it?

Comment: You need two update statements. If you want to make sure that it happens atomically, use a transaction

Answer (score 0):

Set DB2 CLP to autocommit OFF and use `;` command terminator:

```
db2 +c -t 
update catentry   set buyable=0   where partnumber='some value';
update catentdesc set published=0 where catentry_id IN 
(SELECT catentry_id FROM catentry where partnumber='some value');
commit;
```

Comment: Technically, this doesn't accomplish the update in one statement, since you literally issue two `UPDATE` statements inside of a script..  If it's not possible to do it in one, you at least need to state that as not being the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this in a single statement, but recent versions of DB2 for LUW (and, with some restrictions, DB2 for z/OS) support what is called *data change table references* that allow tricks like

```
WITH t1 (catentry_id) AS (
   SELECT catentry_id FROM FINAL TABLE (
      UPDATE catentry SET buyable = 0 WHERE partnumber = 'some value'
   )
), t2 (catentry_id) AS (
   SELECT catentry_id FROM FINAL TABLE (
      UPDATE catentdesc SET published = 0 WHERE catentry_id = (
         SELECT catentry_id FROM t1
      )
   )
) SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Note that the actual statement must be a `SELECT` from something, and `UPDATE` statements are also wrapped in their own `SELECT`s, but this is executed as a single statement.

Comment: If the following error is raised, then it's not supported in the version you're using   `-20165
AN SQL DATA CHANGE STATEMENT WITHIN A FROM CLAUSE IS NOT ALLOWED IN THE CONTEXT IN WHICH IT WAS SPECIFIED`

Comment: Yes, there are various restrictions in different versions; the above tested to work on DB2 for LUW 10.5 fix pack 7 (so it should work on 11.1 as well).